# CBC MAC attack using Arbitrary-length Messages

Tags: cbc-mac, forgery

This is from a lecture :

The adversary sees the message-tag pair(m,τ), where m= (m1,m2,...,mn)The adversary sees the message-tag pair(m′,τ′), where m′= (m′1,m′2,...,m′n)The adversary computes m''=(m1,...,mn,m′1⊕τ,m′2,...,m′n)
The message-tag pair( m'',τ′)is a forgery

But I don't understand why xoring the tag τ of the first message with the 2nd message gives a message whose tag is the tag of the second message.

How is first tag used to determine that the tag of m'' is τ′?

Comment: What is the CBC-MAC of the following messages?  1. $(m)$  2. $(m')$  3. $(m, m' + \tau)$, where $\tau$ is the CBC-MAC of $m$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forge CBC-MAC by creating new message, giving the MAC of two messages](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41662/forge-cbc-mac-by-creating-new-message-giving-the-mac-of-two-messages) also [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11538/18298)

Comment: This looks so much like the other question that I closed it. However, if that's not the case then please explain the differences in a comment below and flag to reopen.